# How to get Image Uri in Android Q?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-external-storage, android-10.0

I want to to get the Uri of a file location in Android Q. I am using the below code, however, Android Studio states it is deprecated. How to get the Uri of a file the right way?

```
val file = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/meter"), "lalaland.jpg")

val uri = Uri.fromFile(file)
```

Comment: [You do not have access to that file location](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html). Either have the user put the files somewhere that you can access via the filesystem (e.g., `getExternalFilesDir()`), or use `MediaStore`, or use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: Thank you are there any tutorials for MediaStore? unable to find documentation on how to use it. @CommonsWare

Comment: I do not know what you are going to do with the `Uri` or what the scope is of what you are trying to do. [This Kotlin sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/tree/v0.4/ConferenceVideos) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Q) shows getting `Uri` values for videos given a filename. In general, you use `query()` on a `ContentResolver` to query your desired type of media.

Comment: Using this Cropping Library which requires Uri https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop, will check that example.

Comment: OK, then you need to focus on how you are asking the user for what image to crop. The code in your question assumes a particular filename in a particular directory. A better solution is `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, allowing the user to pick an image from anywhere on their device (or from cloud storage providers, like Google Drive). You will get a `Uri` that should work with uCrop.

Comment: The Uri is for just saving the Image, i am getting the Image using another library it just does like what u have said, but i does not have method to save image

Answer (score 0):

This function will **return Uri according the given displayName** for file. You can update it to Image like *MediaStore.Images....*

```
public static Uri getUriFromDisplayName(Context context, String displayName) {

    String[] projection;
    projection = new String[]{MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID};

    // TODO This will break if we have no matching item in the MediaStore.
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(extUri, projection,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?", new String[]{displayName}, null);
    assert cursor != null;
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
        long fileId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);

        cursor.close();
        return Uri.parse(extUri.toString() + "/" + fileId);
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String)` has been deprecated to improve user privacy. If you have reference to a `Context` (say, `ctx`), you can do the following:

```
val file = File(ctx.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "meter/lalaland.jpg")

val uri = Uri.fromFile(file)
```

Consult [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Context?hl=en#getExternalFilesDir(kotlin.String)) for more info on how `getExternalFilesDir()` works.

Answer (score 0):

for android Q Access media files from shared storage
To provide a more enriched user experience, many apps allow users to contribute and access media that's available on an external storage volume. The framework provides an optimized index into media collections, called the media store, that allows for retrieving and updating these media files more easily.**scoped storage android** [scoped storage android add an item to collection](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#add-item)

```
public static Uri getImageContentUri(Context context, File imageFile) {
    String filePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{MediaStore.Images.Media._ID},
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=? ",
            new String[]{filePath}, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
        cursor.close();
        return Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + id);
    } else {
        if (imageFile.exists()) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
                Uri picCollection = MediaStore.Images.Media
                        .getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
                ContentValues picDetail = new ContentValues();
                picDetail.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, imageFile.getName());
                picDetail.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
                picDetail.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,"DCIM/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                picDetail.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING,1);
                Uri finaluri = resolver.insert(picCollection, picDetail);
                picDetail.clear();
                picDetail.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
                resolver.update(picCollection, picDetail, null, null);
                return finaluri;
            }else {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
                return context.getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
            }

        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```